# Environment variable does not show up when executing set command

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

One of our applications relies on existence of environment variable that is being set by our server installation. After installing the server I can confirm presence of this variable using 'Environment Variables' dialog. However, when client application executes, calls to set command and Java's *`System.getenv()`* method omit this variable, all others are present. What's interesting is that this failure to read particular environment variable only happens on `Windows 7 64-bit machine`, on `Windows XP 32-bit` this does not happen. The same code on 32-bit machine returns environment variable set by our server installation. I am not sure if difference between `Windows 7` and `Windows XP` plays role here. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to approach this issue?

Comment: `getEnv` returns a case sensitive based `map` on all platforms. BTW, what is the outcome of `System.getProperties()`? Does is contain the env variable you are searching for?

Comment: @Ravinder it does not. I suppose because mine is not a system property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, and I didn't know this, Windows 7 has two cmd.exe commands - one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit environment. When I was running cmd.exe for 32-bit environment I did not see my variable, but when I ran cmd.exe for 64-bit environment, the variable was there.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check

1) what happens when you type `echo %VARNAME%` it is likely not too far from what Java is doing behind the scenes.

2) Is this a system wide environmental variable or a per user one?  It shouldn't make a difference but it might

3) Can you post your code.  The below snippit worked fine for me, does this work for you?

`String path = System.getenv("PATH");`

Comment: 1) No output is printed and when I execute set command my variable, which is a system variable is not printed.
2) It's a system variable
3) This is the code I am using and both produce same result: 
p = r.exec("cmd.exe /c set"); //$NON-NLS-1$
Map<String, String> getenv = System.getenv();